# Ansible 1.5 still failing find host

Tags: linux, ansible

Can u spot anything wrong on host definition below?

```
# ansible --list-hosts -i inventory  -m fortimgr revision.yml
No hosts matched
root@vuwunicoids0001:/home/scripts/fortimanager# cat inventory
[all:vars]
ansible_python_interpreter=python

[fortimanager]
vuwvapcofmg0001 ansible_ssh_host=10.190.10.75 ansible_ssh_user=automation ansible_ssh_password=abc123
root@vuwunicoids0001:/home/scripts/fortimanager# cat revision.yml
---
- name: DEMONSTRATE REVISIONS
  hosts: fortimanager
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: CREATE NEW REVISION
      fortimgr_revision:
        host: "{{ ansible_ssh_host }}"
        username: "{{ ansible_ssh_user }}"
        password: "{{ ansible_ssh_password }}"
        adom: "root"
        created_by: "automation"
        description: "ADOM Revision"
        revision_name: "Lab Revision"

    - name: DELETE REVISION
      fortimgr_revision:
        host: "{{ ansible_ssh_host }}"
        username: "{{ ansible_ssh_user }}"
        password: "{{ ansible_ssh_password }}"
        adom: "root"
        revision_name: "Lab Revision"
        state: "absent"

    - name: RESTORE REVISION
      fortimgr_revision:
        host: "{{ ansible_ssh_host }}"
        username: "{{ ansible_ssh_user }}"
        password: "{{ ansible_ssh_password }}"
        adom: "root"
        created_by: "automatino"
        description: "ADOM Revert"
        revision_name: "Good Revision"
        restore_name: "Rollback"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with what you're doing.

- **Problem:** You're passing `revision.yml` as the host pattern to the `ansible` command, which is why there are no hosts matched.

  **Solution:** You are actually trying to run a playbook, so you should be using the `ansible-playbook` command instead of `ansible`.
- **Problem:** There is no such module as `fortimgr` in Ansible.

  **Solution:** Remove `-m fortimgr` from your command that now begins with `ansible-playbook`.